# Render DIV tag inside table using ASP .net MVC HTML helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to render some DIV inside a table td tag using HTML Helper methods in ASP .net MVC. For some reason, the divs are not being rendered. here is my sample code. My Model has two properties ID and a list of Strings. The strings are basically HTML DIV tags.

```
<table>
<tr>
 <th>ID</th>
 <th>Schedule</th>
</tr>
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
  <tr>
    <td><%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID) %></td>
    <td>
       <% foreach (var bar in item.Details)
        {
           Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => bar);
        }       
        %>
    </td>
   </tr>
 <% } %>
</table>
```

The view is populated with the ID but not the DIV tags. Can someone point to me what I could be doing wrong.

Thanks,
Javid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `<%: %>` around the `Html.DisplayFor`

```
<td>
   <% foreach (var bar in item.Details) { %>
       <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => bar) %>
   <% } %>
</td>
```

because the `Html.DisplayFor` doesn't write directly to the Response just returns the rendered template as a `MvcHtmlString`, so it's need to be "outputted" with the `<%: %>`.

Comment: Thanks. Now, I get the DIV rendered as text instead of actual div element. In my page source I don't see <div> but &ltdiv..

Comment: Then change `<%:` to `<%=` then it won't do html encoding.

Comment: Thanks. I changed Html.DisplayFor to Html.Raw and now the DIV are rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's .getJSON in conjunction with the .html method to spit out HTML markup which contains the DIV:

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(
                        function () {
                            $("#Button2").click(
                                    function () {
                                        $("#ohyeah").html("blah blah blah");
                                        var jsonlisteningobject = {};
                                        $.getJSON("/home/somefoo", null, function (data) {
                                            var div = $('#ohyeah');
                                            div.html("<td>" + data.someNumber + "</td><td>" + data.someString1 + "</td><td>" + data.someString2 + "</td><td>" + data.someListofStrings[3] + "</td>");
                                        }
                                            );
                                        $.getJSON("/home/someHTML", null, function (data) {
                                            $("#someHTMLstuff").html(data);

                                        });
                                    }
                                );

        });
    </script>
```

'someHTMLstuff' and 'ohyeah' can be DIV elements on your page.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. For now, I prefer not to use any JSON stuff, unless JSON is the only way to render HTML markup.